# C++ ld linker --wrap option does not work for internal function calls

Tags: c++, unit-testing, linker, mocking, ld

I am trying to implement some unit tests for a C++ library that does not use OO (all functions are declared at namespace level)

For that purpose, I am trying to create a test binary that mocks (simulate) some functions.

I have achieved the above for functions that I call directly, but **I have been unable to replace the calls that the library's functions do**. The example below explains this:

## Production code

Lets suppose this is the production code, the one that uses the real functions instead of the simulated ones:

**CameraHandler.H**

```
namespace Cam {
    int myFunc();
    int myFunc2();
}
```

**CameraHandler.cpp**

```
#include "CameraHandler.h"

using namespace Cam;

int Cam::myFunc() {
    // Imagine this is the function I want to simulate with a mock
    // Its mangled name is _ZN3Cam6myFuncEv
    return 1;
}

int Cam::myFunc2(){
    return Cam::myFunc() + 11;
}
```

## Testing code

This is the code for the unit testing. As you can see in the Makefile, it generates a binary called **testsMain**.

**CameraHandlerMock.h**

```
extern "C" {
    int __wrap__ZN3Cam6myFuncEv(); // mangled name of Cam::myFunc(), with the __wrap_ prefix.
}
```

**CameraHandlerMock.cpp**

```
#include "CameraHandlerMock.h"

int __wrap__ZN3Cam6myFuncEv(){
    // As you can see, the mocked function returns 999 instead of 1.
    return 999;
}
```

**UnitTestsMain.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>
#include "CameraHandler.h"
#include "CameraHandlerMock.h"

extern "C" int _ZN3Cam6myFuncEv();

int main(){
    std::cout << Cam::myFunc() << std::endl;
    std::cout << Cam::myFunc2() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

**The Makefile**

```
WRAP=-Wl,--wrap,_ZN3Cam6myFuncEv

all: production unitTests

production: // does not matter for this example
        g++ main.cpp CameraHandler.cpp -o main 

unitTests:
        g++ ${WRAP} UnitTestsMain.cpp CameraHandlerMock.cpp CameraHandler.cpp -o testsMain
```

## The problem

If I execute the `testsMain` program, I obtain the following result:

```
999 // call to Cam::myFunc()
12 // Cam::myFunc2(), which is Cam::myFunc() + 11.
```

Taking into account that `Cam::myFunc2()` calls to `Cam::myFunc1()`, and I have replaced it by `__wrap__ZN3Cam6myFuncEv`, what I expect is that t he result of calling `Cam::myFunc2()` is `999 + 11 = 1010`. Nevertheless, `Cam::myFunc2()` is still calling the non-wrapped `Cam::myFunc1()`, so the result is `12`.

**Is there any way to wrap functions that are internally called by the library I want to test**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's lint a little bit of fluff first. In `UnitTestsMain.cpp`,
the declaration:

```
extern "C" int _ZN3Cam6myFuncEv();
```

is redundant. It simply instructs the C++ compiler that references to the function
of that prototype whose *mangled* name is `_ZN3Cam6myFuncEv` are references to
an externally defined function of that name. This is exactly the same information,
just expressed differently, that that the compiler has already got from:

```
namespace Cam {
    int myFunc();
    ...
}
```

when it `#include`-ed `CameraHandler.h`, because `_ZN3Cam6myFuncEv()` is the mangled
form of `Cam::myFunc`. The `extern "C"` redeclaration of `Cam::myFunc` is harmless
but contributes nothing either to compilation or linkage.

On to the main question: Why does your mock 
`int __wrap__ZN3Cam6myFuncEv()` get called instead of `int Cam::myFunc` in `UnitTestsMain.cpp`:

```
int main(){
    std::cout << Cam::myFunc() << std::endl;
    std::cout << Cam::myFunc2() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

as you want; but your mock is *not* called for `int Cam::myFunc` in `CameraHandler.cpp`:

```
int Cam::myFunc2(){
    return Cam::myFunc() + 11;
}
```

The answer lies in [the documentation of the `--wrap` linker option](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/Options.html#Options):

> --wrap=symbol
>
> Use a wrapper function for symbol. Any undefined reference to symbol will be
>   resolved to __wrap_symbol. Any undefined reference to __real_symbol will be
>   resolved to symbol.

Maybe you read it and didn't grok the significance of *undefined reference*.

This means that when `--wrap=symbol` is in effect, and the linker applies it
to an object file containing *undefined* references to `symbol`, it will replace them
with references to `__wrap_symbol`, and *undefined* references to `__real_symbol`,
in that object file, will be replaced with `symbol`.

Now in `UnitTestsMain.o`, compiled from `UnitTestsMain.cpp`, the references to both `Cam::myFunc()`
and `Cam::myFunc2()` are undefined. These functions are both defined in `CameraHandler.cpp`,
compiled in `CameraHandler.o`.

Therefore in the linkage of `UnitTestsMain.o`, `--wrap ZN3Cam6myFuncEv` will take effect and
replace the call to `Cam::myFunc` ( = `ZN3Cam6myFuncEv`) with a call to `__wrap_ZN3Cam6myFuncEv`.
The call to `Cam::myFunc2()` ( = `ZN3Cam7myFunc2Ev`) is not wrapped and is unaffected: it will be
resolved to the definition to be found in `CameraHandler.o`

But in the linkage of `CameraHandler.o`, both functions are defined, so `--wrap` has
no effect. When `Cam::myFunc2()` calls Cam::myFunc(), it calls `ZN3Cam6myFuncEv`, not
`__wrap_ZN3Cam6myFuncEv`.

That explains why the program outputs:

```
999
12
```

and not:

```
999
1010
```

Can you make your mocking work as expected?

Yes. You just have to ensure that every call to `Cam::myFunc` that you want to be
mocked is compiled into an object file that does not contain the (real) definition
of `Cam::myFunc`. The obvious way to do that is to define `Cam::myFunc` in its own
source file. Here's your example fixed:

**CameraHandler.h**

```
#ifndef CAMERAHANDLER_H
#define CAMERAHANDLER_H

namespace Cam {
    int myFunc();
    int myFunc2();
}

#endif
```

**CameraHandlerMock.h**

```
#ifndef CAMERAHANDLERMOCK_H
#define CAMERAHANDLERMOCK_H

extern "C" {
    int __wrap__ZN3Cam6myFuncEv();

}

#endif
```

**CameraHandler_myFunc.cpp**

```
#include "CameraHandler.h"

using namespace Cam;

int Cam::myFunc() {
    return 1;
}
```

**CameraHandler_myFunc2.cpp**

```
#include "CameraHandler.h"

using namespace Cam;

int Cam::myFunc2(){
    return Cam::myFunc() + 11;
}
```

**CameraHandlerMock.cpp**

```
#include "CameraHandlerMock.h"

int __wrap__ZN3Cam6myFuncEv() {
    return 999;
}
```

**UnitTestsMain.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "CameraHandler.h"
#include "CameraHandlerMock.h"

int main(){
    std::cout << Cam::myFunc() << std::endl;
    std::cout << Cam::myFunc2() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

**Makefile**

```
SRCS := UnitTestsMain.cpp CameraHandler_myFunc.cpp \
    CameraHandler_myFunc2.cpp CameraHandlerMock.cpp
OBJS := $(SRCS:.cpp=.o)

LDFLAGS := -Wl,--wrap,_ZN3Cam6myFuncEv

.PHONY: unitTests clean

unitTests: testsMain

testsMain: $(OBJS)
    $(CXX) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $^

UnitTestsMain: CameraHandler.h CameraHandlerMock.h
CameraHandler_Func.o CameraHandler_Func2.o: CameraHandler.h
CameraHandlerMock.o: CameraHandlerMock.h

clean:
    rm -f $(OBJS) testsMain
```

*(Your production build is not considered at all in this example makefile)*

With this, the test build runs like:

```
$ make
g++    -c -o UnitTestsMain.o UnitTestsMain.cpp
g++    -c -o CameraHandler_myFunc.o CameraHandler_myFunc.cpp
g++    -c -o CameraHandler_myFunc2.o CameraHandler_myFunc2.cpp
g++    -c -o CameraHandlerMock.o CameraHandlerMock.cpp
g++ -Wl,--wrap,_ZN3Cam6myFuncEv -o testsMain UnitTestsMain.o \
CameraHandler_myFunc.o CameraHandler_myFunc2.o CameraHandlerMock.o
```

and `testsMain` does what you expect:

```
$ ./testsMain 
999
1010
```

You can simplify both source files and the makefile somewhat if you rewrite 
`CameraHandlerMock.cpp` as just:

```
extern "C" {

int __wrap__ZN3Cam6myFuncEv() {
    return 999;
}

}
```

Then you have no need for the mock header file `CameraHandlerMock.h` at all.

If you have a lot of functions you need to mock in this low-level way, it
may get tedious to define each one in its own source file. You may be aware
that there are higher-level, framework-supported mocking options, e.g. [googlemock](https://github.com/google/googlemock),
that have rich mocking capabilities and don't entail this tedium. It's fair to say, however, that they may
replace it with more complicated kinds of tedium.

Comment: Yes I am already using googlemock for C++ unit tests. I write this post because I wanted a way to mock namespace-level functions, which, as far as I know, you can't mock directly with google mock, since you need to inject an interface.

Comment: That's a point I hadn't considered in favour of this way. Was worth answering the 3-month old Q :)